# Getting a specific group of binary numbers in an Int?

Tags: python, bit-shift

If I am trying to get a specific range of bits (in decimal) at a specific range, is the best way to go about this leftshifting to the end index, and then right shifting back to the start index?

```
#pesudo-code:
    def group(aNumber,start, end):
        n = aNumber << 32 - n
        a = n >> end - start
        print(a)
```

Comment: "trying to get a specific range of bits (in decimal) at a specific range" - what ???

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. If I have an int, I would like to extract the group of binary numbers that represent a certain index of that int. e.g. 5000, if end = 3 and start = 2, the binary number output should be 50. e.g. 0110 0010

Comment: That won't work. Because Python will automatically turn the int into a long (which is essentially unlimited in size, and only constrained by your memory), so you can never get rid of bits on the left. Eg, `5 << 64 = 92233720368547758080L`. Keep in mind that integers in Python don't work like those in C.

Comment: Oh...could I do something similar in C? If possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in python, you're just not using the correct method. When you want to retrieve part of a number, the operation you're trying to accomplish is called masking.

And you do that with a mask: `number & 0xF0` will retreive bits 4 to 7 (without moving them).
So `(number & 0xF0) >> 4` will retrieve bits 4 to 7, and shift them all the way to the right.

As for the mask, `((1 << end) - 1) - ((1 << start) - 1)` should build a correct mask. So...

```
mask = ((1 << end) - 1) - ((1 << start) - 1)
result = (number & mask) >> start
```

Actually, since you shift to the right right after, you don't even have to mask out the bits *below* those you want, so this will work just as well:

```
mask = ((1 << end) - 1)
result = (number & mask) >> start
```

Comment: Does this answer the question? I think the OP wanted a mask, but they wanted one in decimal, not in binary, like you've done. E.g. `group(5000,2,3) = 50`, which is not what your code does.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get from bit `b0` a total of `bn` bits:

```
def getbits(x, b0, bn):
    return (x >> b0) & ((1 << bn) - 1)
```